# How can I combine navbar and pagination?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, navbar

I want to go to a new tab when I click on each item of the navbar however I am using pagination (not sure if I am using it correctly) and it guides me to the expected page section but in the same page not in a new tab. How can I fix this?

```
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-fixed-top pagination pagination-sm">
    <div class="nav navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active page-item" href="#monajalal">Mona Jalal <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="#education">Education</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="#experience">Experience</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="#courseworks">Courseworks</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="#teaching">Teaching</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="#projects">Projects</a>
        <a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right m-r-0" href="https://github.com/monajalal"><i class="fa fa-github fa-lg"></i></a>
        <a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right m-r-2" href="https://twitter.com/MonaJalal_"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a>
        <a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right m-r-4" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mona-jalal"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg"></i></a>
        <a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right m-r-6" href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2414957/mona-jalal"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow fa-lg"></i></a>

    </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding target="_blank" could help, for example:

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="#education" target="_blank">Education</a>
```

Comment: so even though it opens it in a new tab, I can still browse to the whole content and see stuffs from other pages

Comment: Ah I see.  Target="_blank" opens the link in the new tab. Since the link is relative, this opens your homepage in a new tab, and then the # tells it to scroll to a section with a matching ID.

What you might be wanting is to create several different pages, one for each section. Then have the href point to that page (href="/subsections/this_section.html").  This way, the user can scroll the home page through different sections, or they can use the navbar to get to a specific section page.  Am I making sense?